# Could we implement resful webservice via Jersey without manven and web.xml on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, tomcat

I am trying to implement a very simple restful webservice via Jersey and I keep getting a 404 error page without any other error on the console.

Here is the tutorial that I diligently followed.

http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/08/rest-api-service-made-easy-with-jersey-framework-in-java/

Since I am not using maven, I did not document any dependencies.
I am using Eclipse Java EE luna / Tomcat 8 / Java 8 / Servlet 3.0 ( I don't have any web.xml)

I loaded the Jersey 2.22.1 libraries

Is there something that I am missing to make it work?  Should I convert it to a maven project?

Thanks a lof for your help in advance.

*********Response***************
1. Download the jersey library
2. Upload them in the application in the web-inf/lib folder  and add them in the Java build path 
3. Create an HelloApp.java class

```
`package testwebservice.rest.demo; 

    import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;  

    @ApplicationPath("/rest")
       public class HelloApp extends ResourceConfig {
            public void AppConfig() {
                packages("testwebservice.rest.demo");
           }
        }`
```

4. Create HelloWorldService.java class

```
`package testwebservice.rest.demo;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;  
@Path("/hi")
        public class HelloWorldService
        {
          @GET
          @Path("/{name}")
          public Response getMessage(@PathParam("name") String name)
              {
                String outMsg = "Hello " + name + "!";
               return Response.status(200).entity(outMsg).build();
              }
            }`
```

5. Project / Clean in eClips
6. Start the server
7. Test the link "localhost:8080/testwebservice/rest/hi/Test"

result= Hello Test!

Comment: i think you need `web.xml`, cos `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` are both defined in it. The 404 error was due to no mapping found.If you don't want to use maven, make sure you download all the `libs` needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  My understanding is that the annotation @ApplicationPath("/rest") in the HelloApp.java has this purpose.  But I agree with your analysis, this is probably a mapping issue.  The library may be a good starting point for investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *all* the jars from the [Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html), you don't need a web.xml. Just just need an [`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) sublcass, annotated with [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html). So this is the most minimal required configuration

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {}
```

Just having this empty class will trigger class-path scanning, which will scan for classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Provider` classes.

As mentioned [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/when_to_use_jax_rs) class-path scanning is not recommended though. Better to use Jersey's package scanning capabilities. First instead of extending `Application`, you should extend `ResourceConfig` (which is an `Application` subclass). Then just call `packages("..")` to list the package to scan for your resources

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        packages("your.packages.to.scan");
    }
}
```

And that's it. You should be up and running, as long as your resource class is structured properly. And make sure all your jars are actually in your WEB-INF/lib when deployed to Tomcat.

**See Also:**

- [Servlet Based Deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet) for other deployment options (information)

Comment: Great it work !!! I will update the question with the steps that I followed, in case others would be intersted

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the tomcat servlet requires a `web.xml` at the very least.

`Maven/gradle` makes dependency management and building/deploying applications extremely easy, i would recommend this.

On another note: If you just need a simple small web service, take a look at `spring-boot`. It has an embedded tomcat server. No setup needed what so ever, other than a simple maven / gradle setup.

Take a look here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, this is to add to an existing project.